# Center of $D_6$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

> The center of $D_6$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I have that
$$D_6=\left< a,b \mid a^6=b^2=e,\, ba=a^{-1}b\right>$$
$$\Rightarrow D_6=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,b,ab,a^2b,a^3b,a^4b,a^5b\}.$$
My method for trying to do this has been just checking elements that could be candidates. I've widdled it down to that the only elements that commute with all of $D_6$ must be $\{e,a^3\}$ but I got there by finding a pair of elements that didn't commute for all other elements and I still haven't even shown that $a^3$ commutes with everything. For example, I have been trying to show now that
$$a^3b=ba^3$$
and haven't gotten too far yet but if I had to answer a question like this on the exam, I feel it would be difficult, is there any kind of trick or hints other than brute force using the relations to get that $a^3$ commutes with everything?

For the solution once I have that the center of $D_6$ is what I think then as there is only one group of order $2$ up to isomorphism, it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Ideally a way that doesn't appeal to $D_6$ as symmetries of the hexagon if that seems possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote up a general classification for the centers of $D_n$, (the dihedral group of order $2n$, not $n$) just the other week. Perhaps it will be useful to read:

If $n=1,2$, then $D_n$ is of order $2$ or $4$, hence abelian, and $Z(D_n)=D_n$. Suppose $n\geq 3$. We have the presentation
$$
D_n=\langle x,y:x^2=y^n=1,\; xyx=y^{-1}\rangle.
$$
Then $yx=xy^{-1}$ implies the reduction $y^kx=xy^{-k}$. An element is in the center iff it commutes with $x$ and $y$, since $x$ and $y$ generate $D_n$. Let $z=x^iy^j$ be in the center. From $zy=yz$ we see
$$
x^iy^{j+1}=yx^iy^j\implies x^iy=yx^i.
$$
But $i\neq 1$, else we have $xy=yx=xy^{-1}$, so $y^2=1$, a contradiction since $n\geq 3$. So $i=0$, and $z=y^j$. Then from the equation $zx=xz$, we have
$$
y^jx=xy^j=xy^{-j}
$$
which implies $y^{2j}=1$. Thus $j=0$ or $j=n/2$. If $n$ is odd, we must necessarily have $j=0$, and $z=1$. If $n$ is even, either possibility works. But $y^{n/2}$ is indeed in the center as it clearly commutes with $y$, as well as with $x$ since $y^{n/2}x=xy^{-n/2}=x(y^{n/2})^{-1}=xy^{n/2}$. Summarizing, we have, for $n\geq 3$,
$$
Z(D_n)=\begin{cases}
\{1,y^{n/2}\} & \text{if }n\equiv 0\pmod{2},\\
\{1\} & \text{if }n\equiv 1\pmod{2}.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

General method to find the centre of $D_{2n}$

if $n=1$ or $n=2$ ,then $D_{2n}$ is abelian  and hence  $Z(D_{2n})= D_{2n}.$

Now suppose $ n \ge 3$  .By definition  we have

$D_{2n} = \{ a^ib^j :i=0,1 , j=0,1,....., n-1\}$ where $a$ is an element of order $2$, $b$ is an element  of order $n$  and $a, b$ are given  by relation $ ba=ab^{-1}$

Then its implies  $bba=b^2a = bab^{-1}=ab^{-1}b^{-1}=ab^{-2}.$

In general form we can write

$b^ra=ab^{-r}\tag1$

For all integer  $r \ge 0$.Now , since $a$ and $b$ together generate  $D_{2n}$, an element of  $D_{2n}$ is in center if and only  if its commutes with both $a$ and $b$.

Therefore $ x= a^ib^j \in Z(D_{2n})$ if and only if $xa=ax$ and $xb=bx$.

$x b= a^ib^j b=a^ib^{j+1}= bx= ba^ib^j$ where $x= a^ib^j$

Therefore $a^ib=ba^i \tag 2$

we can see clearly $i=0$ in $(2)$ because  $a^0b=ba^0$ implies $ b=b$

we can  see clearly $i \neq 1$ because  if $i=1$ then $ab=ba$ but from $(1)$ , for $n \ge 3$ we have  $ab=ba^{-1} \neq ba$
so we are getting contradiction  if $i=1$

we have have $x=a^ib^j$ . If $i=0$ then $x= a^0b^j=b^j$

Now the  condition $xa=ax$ t becomes $b^ja=ab^j$

from $(1)$ relation we have $ab^{-j}=ab^j$

There $ b^{-j}=b^j$ implies $b^{2j}=1 \tag 3$

Since  order$(b)=n$ (given), we get  from $(3)$ that $$n |2j$$
Therefore  if $n$ divide $2j$ then  $j=0$ or $2j=n$

Now if $j=0$ then $x=b^j=b^0=1$

If $2j=n$ , then $n$ is even , that is $j= \frac{n}{2}$

so $x=b^j=b^{n/2}$

so we have proved that $$Z(D_{2n})= \begin{cases} D_{2n} \ \text{if n=1 ,2} \\ \{1\}\  \text{if n > 2 is odd} \\ \{1,b^{n/2}\} \ \text{if n >2 is even } \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

It does not give proofs, but given the tone of the original question a good graphical tool for the OP would be Group Explorer. It does a lot of the donkey work, and can show you various visualisations, including the multiplication tables in helpful ways.

http://groupexplorer.sourceforge.net/

For $D_6$, that $Z_2$ is the center is (to me a least) kinda obvious by just looking at the pictures of the multication table sorted by it's various subgroups. eg below is $D_6$ with the required subgroup shown in top left - note the first 2 rows and 2 columns match exactly, whereas other rows/columns don't.

[image: Center of D6]

Answer (score 0):

Check that $a^{k}b=(a^{k}b)^{-1},k=1,2,3,4,5$. Then since $ba^k=(a^{6-k}b)^{-1}$ (multiply them), then since $(a^{6-k}b)^{-1}=a^{6-k}b, a^{6-k}b=ba^{k}\Rightarrow $
every element of $D_{6}$ may be written as as $a^{k}b^{l}$.Then two things:

(1) If $a^kb=ba^k\Rightarrow a^kb=a^{6-k}b\Rightarrow a^{k}=a^{6-k}\Rightarrow k\equiv 6-k(\text{mod }6)\Rightarrow k=3\Rightarrow a^3$ is the only element not 
equal to $b$ that commutes with $b$. Since $ab = ba^5, b$ is not in the center.

(2) $a^{3}
(a^{k}b)=a^{3}(ba^{6-k})=(a^{3}b)a^{6-k}=(ba^3)a^{6-k}=b(aa^{6-k})=b(a^{6-k}a)=
(ba^{6-k})a^3=(a^{k}b)a^3\Rightarrow a^{3}$ commutes with all $a^{k}b$.

We already know that $a^3$ commutes with every other $a^{k}$. By (2), $a^3$ is in the center. By (1), $a^3$ is the only nontrivial element in the center.